# Is using any indeterminate value undefined or just those stored in objects with automatic storage?

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior, c11

According to C99 J.2, the behavior is undefined when:

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate

What about all the other cases where an object has an indeterminate value? Do we also always invoke UB if we use them? Or do we invoke UB only when they contain a trap representation?

Examples include:

- the value of an object allocated using `malloc` (7.20.3.3p2)
- [storing in non-automatic storage] a `FILE*` after calling `fclose` on it (7.19.3p4)
- [storing in non-automatic storage] a pointer after calling `free` on it (6.2.4p2)

...and so on.

---

I've used C99 for my references, but feel free to refer to C99 or C11 in your answer.

Comment: Just asking, even if it is "safe", what purpose will it serve?

Comment: @SouravGhosh This particular question occurred to me while I was about to ask another question -- not out of something that I was actually trying to write. Basically I'm trying to understand whether some optimizations I come up with are allowed by the spec.

Comment: Have in mind that Annex J is not normative and that it is not a complete list of all undefined behavior.

Comment: @JensGustedt I wonder if this particular bulletpoint in J.2 isn't a defect. I can't find any reference in the standard body (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) to accesses to indeterminate automatic-storage objects being UB, provided those objects aren't or couldn't have been declared `register`, and the existence of the 6.3.2.1p2 paragraph, which singles out such `register` objects and automatic objects that could have been declared register, in my opinion strongly suggests that accesses to the not-even-theoretically-`register`, indeterminate `auto` objects are not meant to be UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using C11 revision here:

The definitions from the standard are:

> **indeterminate value**
>
> either an unspecified value or a trap representation
>
> **trap representation**
>
> an object representation that need not represent a value of the object type
>
> **unspecified value**
>
> Unspecified **valid   value**   of   the   relevant   type   where   this   International   Standard   imposes   no
> requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

---

An unspecified value is a valid value of the relevant type and as such it does not cause undefined behaviour. Using a trap representation will.

---

But why this wording exists in the standard is that the excerpt enables compilers to issue diagnostics, or *reject* programs that use the value of uninitialized local variables yet still stay standard-compliant; because there are types of which it is said that they cannot contain trap representations *in memory*, so they'd always be having *unspecified value* there in their indeterminate state. This applies to for example `unsigned char`. And since using an unspecified value does not have undefined behaviour then the standard does not allow one to reject such a program.

Additionally, say an `unsigned char` normally does not have a trap representation... except, IIRC there are computer architectures where a register can be set to "uninitialized", and reading from a register in such an architecture will trigger a fault. Thus even if an `unsigned char` does not really have trap representations in memory, on this architecture it will with cause a hardware fault with 100 % probability, if it is of automatic storage duration and compiler decides to store it in a register and it is still uninitialized at the time of the call.

Comment: No, accessing a trap representation has undefined behaviour; accessing indeterminate value has **possibly** undefined behaviour or possibly completely defined behaviour but unspecified value if the *type cannot have a trap representation*, excepting the case of uninitialized local variables, where it is explicitly stated that it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user694733 however the C standard says what is undefined behaviour standardwise, as in "standard imposes no requirements". An implementation is free to define *exactly which behaviour happens in any of these cases*, so of course **all** undefined behaviour can be defined by the implementation.

Comment: Accessing an indeterminate value can never be well-defined behavior. It is either undefined or unspecified behavior. In the latter case, you get garbage values and you can't know what they are, but at least the program won't crash.

Comment: If we do `void* p1 = malloc(1); free(p1);` and then `void* p2 = malloc(1);` can the implementation statically assume that `p1 != p2`?

Comment: " The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function is used (7.22.3)." is critical undefined behaviour. (C11)

Comment: and @TheodorosChatzigiannakis no. However if you test that you will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala And if we replaced `malloc`/`free` with `fopen`/`fclose` and  we changed `p1`/`p2` to have storage other than automatic, in that case could the implementation statically assume the result of the comparison? (Assuming that `fclose` doesn't necessarily `free` the `FILE*` internally, but simply "magically" makes it indeterminate.)

Comment: Again, I picked bad example, since it's explictly stated. Oh, well... I can't think of any practical example where contents of variable would change from valid to unspecified, and it wouldn't be explicitly stated as UB in standard.

Comment: To clarify this `unsigned char` cannot have trap representations. The "register" case you are referring to is in fact captured by another mechanism in the standard. Accessing an uninitialized object who's address has never been taken has undefined behavior per se, independent of any type considerations or possible trap representations.

Comment: according to DR 451, indeterminate values may be "wobbly" even when no trap representations are present, i.e. it's not the same as "unspecified". (it appears as if unspecified on each access but the value may change between access)

Comment: @JensGustedt indeed, a variable `unsigned char` cannot be have trap representations, I was referring to the fact that indeed on this one architecture an uninitialized variable of type `unsigned char` (whose address is never taken) can have a real *hardware trap* in the register; for such architectures the undefined behaviour will lead to crash 100 % of the time.

Comment: According to the standard, such a "hardware trap" is not allowed to happen if the address of the object is taken anywhere in the code, or stated otherwise, if it is backed by memory.

Comment: @M.M: If `x` is an Indeterminate Value of a type like uint32_t where all bit patterns represent values,  then after `a=x; b=a; c=a; d=x;` what would the Standard say about a, b, c, and d?  I'd expect `d` would not be guaranteed to match `a`, but what about `b` and `c`?  If `b` and `c` wouldn't be guaranteed to match as written, would there be any way to change the first assignment so they would?

Comment: @supercat undefined behaviour unless the address is taken of `x` and `a`  (the Itanium Clause), and after that, all indeterminate

Comment: @M.M: Is there any safe and efficient way to take a value which might be defined or indeterminate, and leave it unchanged if defined, and Unspecified if not?  Such an operation should typically not require generating any code, but I can't think of any approach more efficient than storing the value to an automatic volatile variable, storing its address in a global volatile that nothing will actually read (but which, from the compiler's perspective, something might read), and then reading back the automatic volatile, but that would require that the compiler generate lots of useless code.

Comment: I think it remains indeterminate even after that volatile operation

Comment: @M.M: The other alternative would be to apply, on each `unsigned char` of the value, `unsigned char ret=0; if (n & 1) ret|=1; if (n & 2) ret|=2;` etc. for every bit of the value. In any case, though, I would question how loose interpretations of what "intermediate value" means could facilitate optimization of useful code without an efficient means of solidifying values.  If solidifying a value requires a huge amount of useless code, how would that not negate any speed benefit gained from using Intermediate Values rather than Unspecified?

Comment: @M.M actually I am not sure about that, because the volatile read is required to be issued, e.g. the compiler can't assume any longer that something else didn't set a value there in between.

Comment: @supercat that wouldn't work, as I read the defect reports, the wobbly bits would make all these wobbly and the actual value indeterminate.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: On many systems, it would be possible to configure a hardware trap when an address is written into a particular volatile location, and to have that trap modify the storage whose address was written.  Making an auto variable `volatile` is a way of warning the compiler that such a thing could happen, especially if its address is taken.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Which one wouldn't work?  Whether each "if" branch is taken would be Unspecified, but I don't recall anything saying the code could do anything other than take the branch or not take the branch.

Comment: @M.M: I wonder why people keep referring to the special case of variables whose address is not taken as the "Itanium clause" when for decades the use of unitialized variables could cause behaviors which did not fit any behavioral description in the Standard other than UB [not because they'd do anything really wacky, but because the Standard lacked the means to describe the behavior in more specific terms].  It would be extremely common, for example, for a 32-bit compiler's generated code to regard an uninitialized uint16_t as holding a value outside the range 0-65535.

Comment: @supercat the simplest explanation. You're correct ofc.

Comment: @M.M: A behavioral model that allows for more kinds of non-deterministic behavior and also provides means for coercing possibly-indeterminate values into values that were at worst Unspecified would make it possible to write many kinds of code (e.g. using sparse hash tables) a lot more efficiently than would presently be possible.  If people in charge of standards are genuinely interested in efficiency, why not define things in such a way as to allow algorithms to be expressed efficiently?